# Using my everyday iPhone for iOS app device testing

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, device

Today i signed up to Apple's $99 a year iOS developer program. I'm currently working on certificates, Identifiers and Profiles part so i'd be able to first test my apps on real device. I have available an iPhone 4s, iPhone 5 and iPad mini. These are my family's devices. If i use my mom's iPhone 5 for example to test my apps, would there be any negative affect to the iPhone what-so-ever? Lets say i turn off the device from Xcode and want to use another device, would iPhone 5 malfunction in any way or is it completely safe to use my main everyday device for testing?

Comment: The biggest thing is to avoid installing any beta versions of iOS on your everyday devices. Only do that on devices used only for app development.

Answer (score 4):

No, In no way will it affect your everyday tasks like calling, texting, etc. When you run your project with your phone being the one you want to run it on the app will show up and stop whatever you are doing at the time but it won't have any long term effect on you or your mom's phone. However to make your app go on the phone you need to register the phones you want to use in development mode. If thats done you should be all good

Good Luck and Happy Developing!

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing my app on my everyday iPhone for months now. I've had no issues at all. Nothing affects my iPhone negatively in any way. Also, don't be afraid to delete your app completely from your iPhone if you need to fix something. It also won't have any negative affect on your app or on your phone. Uploading and deleting your app has the same effect on your phone like you download an app from the App Store. That doesn't have any negative affect on your phone. Your uploading your app from Xcode to your phone will not have any negative affect.